# Cancan, RSpec + Stubbing without params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cancan, stub

When I test my controllers I have this kind of code :

```
describe "GET 'show'" do
  let!(:comment) { build_stubbed(:comment) }
  before(:each) { Project.stubs(:find).returns(project) } 

  it "render show template" do
    get 'show', id: project.id
    should render_template('show')
  end

  it "create a new comment" do
    Comment.expects(:new).returns(comment)
    get 'show', id: project.id
  end
end
```

My problem is the following : I have to pass an ID to use the method load_and_authorize_resource à cause de la ligne 139 dans ce code :
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/2.0/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb which check if there is an ID in the parameters.

How to fix that?

Thanks!

Edit :
In other words : the variable @project isn't instaciate by the method load_and_authorize_resource because there is no ID and cancan check if there is a id to find a model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you're asking, but you can do something like:

`before(:each) { Project.stubs(:find).with(anything).returns(project)`

To stub out any call to `Project.find` that takes a single parameter, no matter what that parameter is. Does that help?

Comment: No sorry, the problem is than the variable @project isn't instaciate by the method load_and_authorize_resource, like it should be.

Comment: You're making even less sense now. What `@project` variable, you make no reference to any in your post? Nor do you declare the `project` variable anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, it's just an extract. The `code`project`code` is declarated by a let and `@project` variable is used in my views.

Comment: How can anyone answer you without getting the relevant information!?